# set value using a conditional of a subquery

Tags: sql

Sorry if I am not explaining my issue the best, but basically I have two tables.

Table A has a reference column to table B. On table B there is column X where for each referenced row, there is an unreferenced row with that same value of column X (table B has double the rows of table A). I want to update the reference on table A to be the row of table B that is not currently referenced of the two rows that have the same value on column X.

In pseudo code...

```
update tableA 
  set refCol = (select tableB.refCol 
                from tableB 
                where colX = (select colX 
                              from tableB 
                              where tableB.refCol = tableA.refCol) 
                 and tableB.refCol != tableA.refCol)
```

The innermost query returns two rows, the outer query returns one row

sample tables:

Table A

| refCol |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 3 |

Table B

| refCol | colX |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | hello |
| 2 | hello |
| 3 | hi |
| 4 | hi |

expected output:

Table A

| refCol |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 4 |

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Still not clear. Could you please add sample data and expected output?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions. Make it easy to assist you!

Comment: added sample data/output to OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer it below working example

```
create table #tableA(
id int)

create table #tableB(
id int,
name varchar(10)
)

insert into #tableA values(1)
insert into #tableA values(3)
insert into #tableA values(5)
insert into #tableA values(6)
insert into #tableA values(7)
insert into #tableA values(8)


insert into #tableB values (1,'A')
insert into #tableB values (2,'A')
insert into #tableB values (3,'C')
insert into #tableB values (4,'C')

select * from #tableA
select * from #tableB



update aa set aa.id=ab.id from #tableA aa inner join (
select b.id,b.name,a.id as ta from (
select  B.* from #tableB b left join #tableA a on a.id=b.id where a.id is null)b
inner join (
select b.* from #tableA a inner join #tableB b on a.id=b.id)a on a.name=b.name)ab on aa.id=ab.ta
```

Comment: no, just want to update the reference on table A. added psuedo code to the OP

Comment: @bentestarnao solution is provided. you can refer to the above code